# need to know what this cmd commands mean exactly for restarting windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to know what each part of the below command means exactly, please and need a reference link that can clarify and explain well most commad prompt commands as well if someone knows any.

```
shutdown /r /t 30 /c "Scheduled Reboot task" /d p:0:0 /f
```

thank you,

max

Comment: `help shutdown` will show you

Comment: thanks for fast reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the prompt, use

```
shutdown /?
```

for documentation.